# MariaDB: How to use function in default clause?

Tags: mariadb

I use the freshest MariaDB:

```
select @@version
10.4.8-MariaDB
```

When run this cript:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  uuid_field     VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT (uuid()),
  binary_uuid    BINARY(16)  DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()))
);
```

receive the error:
Function or expression '`UUID_TO_BIN`()' cannot be used in the DEFAULT clause of `binary_uuid`

For the test I run this and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  uuid_field     VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT (uuid()),
  binary_uuid    BINARY(16)
);
```

What is the problem in the 1st case? Is it possible to use user's functions in the DEFAULT clause?

Answer (score 0):

DEFAULT Column Option¶
MariaDB starting with 10.2.1
The DEFAULT clause was enhanced in MariaDB 10.2.1. Some enhancements include

The DEFAULT clause can now be used with an expression or function.

It means: built-in functions only, but not user-defined

Answer (score 0):

Make `binary_uuid` a "Generated column" instead.